# Count total rows excluding children rows

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a requirement for display only row count of parent rows in tree data mode. I am using getDisplayedRowCount api it gives me all the row count i.e parent + child (if expanded). Is there any way to do it?

For example
If we have rows like below where 2 row has child and 1 row has no child then just count as 3 . dont count children.  Just count parent row and row without children

Result count : 3 of 3

Parent row 1
--- Child row

Parent row 2
--- child row

Row without child

For example, if we have tree structure like in the example . How to only count A, C and E? and show count as 3 on top of grid

https://www.ag-grid.com/example-runner/grid-react.php?section=javascript-grid-tree-data&example=filler-nodes&generated=1&clientside=1&rowgrouping=1&enterprise=1&grid=%7B%22noStyle%22%3A0%2C%22height%22%3A%22100%25%22%2C%22width%22%3A%22100%25%22%2C%22enterprise%22%3Atrue%7D

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree-data/

Comment: Hi guys could you please help

Comment: Where's your HTML? How do you think we'll be able to help you without it?

Comment: Code is internal. But the same logic can be applied to existing example in ag grid website https://www.ag-grid.com/example-runner/grid-react.php?section=javascript-grid-tree-data&example=filler-nodes&generated=1&clientside=1&rowgrouping=1&enterprise=1&grid=%7B%22noStyle%22%3A0%2C%22height%22%3A%22100%25%22%2C%22width%22%3A%22100%25%22%2C%22enterprise%22%3Atrue%7D

Comment: any hint would help

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to rely on the fact that the parent node of the nodes A, C & E (in your given example) is the root node - note that this is not documented in the official documentation, however it is the simplest solution I can think of.

If a node has the root node as the parent, then we can call it a parent node.
You can verify this by adding this code and look at the nodes which are printed:

```
gridOptions.api.forEachNode((node) => {
    if (node.parent.id == 'ROOT_NODE_ID') {
      console.log(node.key);
    }
  });
```

I've put together an [example showing this at the click of a button](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZxSCvqlsHSu9fOIW)

Comment: Thanks Shuheb. does that work with grid client side filtering logic too?

Comment: can we do like displayed rows minus all child rows?

Comment: Yes it will work with client side sorting and filtering, you have to change the forEachNode method to: forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort. See here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#reference-rowNodes